# PySerial receiving strange data

Tags: pyserial

I've connected my smart meter with a serial cable. However, when retrieving the data using PySerial I always get these lines:

```
b'\x00\n'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Eventually, I do get some data, but not even all.

Output should be like:

```
/ISk5\2ME382-1003
0-0:96.1.1(4B414C37303035313039)
1-0:1.8.1(00180.724*kWh)
1-0:1.8.2(00001.416*kWh)
1-0:2.8.1(00000.000*kWh)
1-0:2.8.2(00000.000*kWh)
[...]
!
```

My script:

```
import sys
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff=0
ser.rtscts=0
ser.timeout=None
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0"

ser.open()
count=0
stack=[]
while count < 25:
    p1_raw =  str(ser.readline())
    print(p1_raw)
    count=count+1

ser.close()
exit
```

The problem seems to be with Python/PySerial. When using cu or minicom the data is received properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying various settings, this seems to have solved the problem:

> ser.xonxoff=1